# Error while invoking wso2 data service from wso2 esb sequence

Tags: wso2-esb

I am trying to get some data from wso2 data service via wso2 esb sequence as below

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ConcurGetSAEExtractFlow">
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="Debugging" value="ConcurGetSAEExtractFlow" />
   </log>
   <xslt key="GetConcurSAE_Extract_Transformation" />
   <property name="post-data-service-sequence" value="ConcurTransformSAEExtractFlow" />
   <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="false" />
   <send receive="DataServiceInvocationErrorFlow">
      <endpoint key="ConcurDataServiceEndpoint" />
   </send>
   <description />
</sequence>
```

The xslt transformation GetConcurSAE_Extract_Transformation is as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="dat:GetConcurSAEExtract">            
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As seen there is no input mappings for the service and output mappings are provided. I have already tested the service in the wso2 dss "try this service" and it runs well.
But whereas when I am trying to run this through the wso2 esb through a proxy I receive the below error block

```
TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2013-01-25 01:26:24,244]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  Debugging = ConcurGetSAEExtractFlow {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2013-01-25 01:26:24,252]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ClientHandler} -  Received an internal server error : Internal Server Error For : 10.12.46.5:9764 For Request : Axis2Request [Message ID : urn:uuid:2b34a4c3-796e-410b-aa62-47f28f88f8b7] [Status Completed : true] [Status SendingCompleted : true] {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ClientHandler}
TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2013-01-25 01:26:24,253]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil} -  OMException in getSOAPBuilder {org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil}
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.constructNode(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:305)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:252)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createNextOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:234)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:249)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:140)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getSOAPBuilder(BuilderUtil.java:728)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:197)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:145)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:223)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2013-01-25 01:26:24,254]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil} -  Remaining input stream :[] {org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil}
TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2013-01-25 01:26:24,254]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ClientWorker} -  Unexpected response received. HTTP response code : 500 HTTP status : Internal Server Error exception : First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ClientWorker}
TID: [] [WSO2 ESB] [2013-01-25 01:26:24,273]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  status = success response from DSS {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

I am not able to find out what's going wrong which results in this kind of error.Please if anybody have an idea on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not copying the soap envelope and header with your XSLT. Make once a `<log level="full"/>` before and after your `<xslt>` call, then you'll see that your XSLT will also get a `<soap:envelope><soap:body>...`

So you'll have to put that in the output as well.

Pseudo code:

```
<xsl:template match="envelope|body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks.The change I made is as below 
 `<xsl:template match="envelope/body">` 
But this still gives issue and now its failing at the xslt transformation again.I want to get the selected values from the db through the data service(select query) and perform other transformations.The sequence inserts data and then calls the current sequence to get the data.Please let me know if am missing anything.